# CodeCamp algorithm falsy bouncer

Tags: javascript, arrays, boolean

why does this work for every falsy but null?

```
 function bouncer(arr) {
  for(let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(!arr[i]){
      arr.splice(i,1);
      i = 0;
    }
 }
   console.log(arr);
}

bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""])
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the final expression that occurs in a `for` loop, the `i++` here, will always be executed after the loop body. So, given the current logic, no matter what the input array is, `i` will be `0` at the start of the loop body only during the first iteration:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log('i:', i);
    if (!arr[i]) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      i = 0;
    }
  }
  console.log(arr);
}

console.log(bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]));
```

You could reset `i` to `-1` instead, resulting in the `i++` turning `i` to `0` at the start of the next loop body:

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    console.log('i:', i);
    if (!arr[i]) {
      arr.splice(i, 1);
      i = -1;
    }
  }
  console.log(arr);
}

console.log(bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]));
```

Or, of course, use `.filter` instead, `.filter` is far easier to reason about:

```js
const bouncer = arr => arr.filter(Boolean);
console.log(bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]));
```

Answer (score 1):

or you can use

```js
function bouncer(arr){
  return arr.filter(Boolean);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to add something more to the answer given by **CertainPerformance**, also you can handle the increment of `i` inside the loop body, like this:

```js
function bouncer(arr)
{
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length;)
  {
    console.log('i:', i);

    if (!arr[i])
      arr.splice(i, 1);
    else
      i++;
  }

  return arr;
}

console.log(bouncer([false, null, 0, "Some value", NaN, undefined, ""]));
```

Answer (score 0):

arr.splice(i,1), here i has same value as that of the outer loop. So assigning to it 0 wont help.  Also you need to subtract 1 from i: arr.splice(i--,1) so that the entry that's moved down is not skipped.

```js
function bouncer(arr) {

  for(let i=0;i<arr.length;i++){
  
    if(!(arr[i]))
      arr.splice(i--,1);
  }   
  return arr;
  
}

console.log(bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]));
```

Answer (score -1):

```js
function bouncer(arr) {
    return arr.filter(val => val);
}
console.log(bouncer([false, null, 0, NaN, undefined, ""]));
```

Each value would be treated as a boolean and if that a truthly value it would be selected and if falsely rejected.

Comment: This method seems to have been covered in existing answers.